# expected unqualified-id before '.' token (c++ error )

Tags: c++, data-structures, codeblocks

I Keep getting this error, and i don't know why! Please help

```
if(option = '1')
    {
        cout << "What word would you like to do a linear search for?" << endl;
        cin >> word;

        Search.linearSearch(250, word);
        if (comparisons >= true)
        {
            cout << "The word" << word << "was found!" << comparisons << "comparisons were made" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "The word was not found" << endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should probably be `if(option == '1')`

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Best to give complete code that should compile.

Comment: What's `Search` in `Search.linearSearch(250, word)`?

Comment: im getting the error at search.linearSearch(250, word)

Comment: `comparisons >= true` doesn't not make much sense. What's bigger than or equal to true? You probably meant to write `comparisons >= 1`.

Comment: @H2CO3 the error is at line 6

Comment: @dupersuper i'm counting the number of comparisons made. true and false are in my header file

Comment: You shouldn't redefine `true` and `false`. They are special C++ keywords. Anyway, `comparisons` looks to be a number, not a truth value or boolean, so you should treat it like one.

Comment: @dupersuper okay, thanks, it doesn't solve my problem though :(

Comment: In any case, you need to show us what is in you header file. What is `Search` supposed to be referring to? Whatever it is, the compiler can't find it.

Comment: @dupersuper i tried adding more code to the post but its not letting me.. sorry, this is my first time using this

Comment: Do you see the 'edit' link underneath the tags, next to the 'share' and 'flag' links? Click that.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use Search::linearSearch(250, word);

Comment: that doesn't work either, I tried it . i'm trying to call the function not initialize it .

Comment: How is Search defined? Is it a class? You have to create an object:
Search searchObj;
and then use
searchObj.lineSearch(250,word);

Comment: you seems a bit confusing. You are using lineSearch as a method. Try to do this way: Search lineSearch(250,word);